Can't load MaterialDesignColors.ColorManipulation.HsbConverter
When I try to display a control with a material design color picker, I get an System.TypeLoadException.
The full description is:

Could not load type
'MaterialDesignColors.ColorManipulation.HsbConverter' from assembly
'MaterialDesignColors, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=df2a72020bd7962a'.

I'm working with Material Design Themes 4.9.0 and Material Design Color 3.0.0.0
I tried to remove and reinstall the two packages.
I try to downgrade the version of theme and color.
As you can see, the package is installed:

Did someone get this error and fix it ?
Thanks for your time.
Quentin

Downgrade to MaterialDesignColors 2.1.4. It worked in my case.
